# How to disable the Lollipop notification popups while in a game?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, notifications, push-notifications

I know there are fixes for a rooted device  with Android 5.0+ to stop the notification popups for like text messages and apps like facebook. These I've found tend to be perminant and not so easy to do fixes so can't be used as a 'toggle' on / off.

What I am looking for is some way that I can toggle off those notifications at the top of the screen that can interfere with seeing the screen or worse, if I'm drawing a picture it can totally damage the drawing by blocking where I'm working while I'm drawing and because I'm touching the screen there flips me out of the app I'm using and into the other app and sometimes even causes the original app to crash losing all the work.

By default, I have found NO built in option to turn these on or off. I like them when I'm just doing everything else and find them very useful so don't want them 'perma off'.

Anyone know of anyway or anything that may help with this? Is this hard coded in all editions of Lollipop?

EDIT: The model of phone in question is a T-Mobile Note 4 with Android 5.0.1. Model: SM-N910T. This is a rooted Stock rom.

Comment: Switch to priority mode to allow only high priority notifications to come through.

Comment: Priority mode?  Are you referencing the 'Do Not Disturb' mode?

In all honesty, I never thought of manually turning on the 'Do Not Disturb' mode to see if those popups would still go through with that but I currently have that configured for when I'm sleeping. I'll try this.

Comment: No. They are both different. You can set 3 modes: All, Priority Mode, Do not disturb mode. In priority mode, you can actually choose whether to allow interruptions like events and reminders / calls / messages to come through. Do not disturb would block anything indiscriminately; not letting you even know if an important call is coming through.

Comment: The do not desturb mode on my note 4 is not as you describe. I can set it for priority pass through and anyone and any apps on this list will pass through while those that do not will not make sounds or ahow popups. It has also a blanket ignore all mode also.  I have no idea where this 'priority' mode as you describe is. I am on a Tmovile samsung galaxy note 4 with android 5.0.1 lollipop.

Comment: OK. Didn't realize you were using touchwiz. Not surprising you couldn't find that. :) I was mentioning this from the AOSP implementation. For the touchwiz implementation, check [this](http://www.androidcentral.com/galaxy-note-4-volumeinterruption-setup-lollipop-offers-worst-both-worlds) article. Excerpts from the article: `Want to switch to "Priority" interruptions? You'll need to go to Settings > Device > Sounds and notifications > Interruptions, and toggle between the three presets using the dropdown.`

Comment: Sadly, 'Interruptions' is not availible on the SM-N910T model and I don't believe in any of the American ones. Not sure why they made so many varients of the same phone OS and mostly gimping it with the American models.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP has never visited the site after asking the question and no votes on the existing answers). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I know of an app called [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) that can hibernate apps to prevent notifications from popping up.

You can also simply tell it to hibernate with the screen on with the push of a button. Just open up the main screen and if any activities are awake that you want to hibernate, push the zzz button.

Comment: Do correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't Greenify hibernate apps only after the screen turns off. What if I have to play the game without first making my device go to sleep?

Comment: @Firelord It does hibernate selected apps after the screen goes off, but you can also simply tell it to hibernate with the screen on with the push of a button.  Just open up the main screen and if any activities are awake that you want to hibernate, push the zzz button.

Comment: Yes! Now I see it. I kinda forgotten that manual way (being habitual of auto-hibernate :). It seems that OP could use **Tasker** to activate "Greenify Hibernation" using `am start -n com.oasisfeng.greenify/.GreenifyShortcut` whenever his/her special apps are running.

Comment: I don't want to hibernate the app, I could do this using titanium backup and 'freeze' the app. Same thing. The apps need to run in the background. I'm simply trying to prevent the large banner notificiations that appear over full screen apps while a full screen app is running. Yes, I could also turn off the phone/radio options but then defeating the purpose of the device. I would want to still hear the 'ding' or 'ring' depending on what is going on. Lollipop is good to READ someone's name for both calls and such for the notifications aloud.

Comment: Now greenify has a hibernation widget, Just select which all apps are to be hibernated, and each time you click on the widget... whoosh, the app goes for a nap :)